# Meaning of the phrase "Meet the new boss same as the old boss"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was listening to The Who's "Won't Get Fooled Again" and there was a phrase

> "Meet the new boss same as the old boss"

and I was wondering about what this represents?

Comment: It means the new boss ***is*** the same as the old boss (in some significant way). The Who were probably mindful of [Orwell's Animal Farm](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/11670-the-creatures-outside-looked-from-pig-to-man-and-from), where *The creatures outside looked from pig to man, and from man to pig, and from pig to man again; but already it was impossible to say which was which.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase

> Meet the new boss same as the old boss

has the meaning that **nothing changes**.

The Who's song ***Won't Get Fooled Again*** references changing social circumstance

> I'll tip my hat to the new constitution
>   Take a bow for the new revolution
>   Smile and grin at the change all around me

but with the warning that nothing changes

> And the world looks just the same
>   And history ain't changed
>   'Cause the banners, they are flown in the next war

and then ending the song with

> Meet the new boss same as the old boss

It's the Who's elegant way of saying

> [The more things change, the more they stay the same](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_more_things_change,_the_more_they_stay_the_same)

Comment: This is a great answer, but not specific enough; the key point is that this song was recorded in 1971 - it's a cry of disappointment or cynicsm about the outcome of the 'revolutionary' spirit of the 60's